# + / - Quantity box with children

Tags: javascript, opencart

With the help of the stackoverflow community, I have been able to adapt some code to work as +/- buttons with minimum & maximum limits of 1 & 10. All seems to be ok except when I add multiple products into the cart of my testing Opencart website. The first input field works ok, but all following +/- buttons only adjust the first. You can see what I mean in the demo, I have duplicated the html blocks to illustrate the problem I am getting - http://jsfiddle.net/aeuLx9nt/5/

This must be something in the javascript causing this. I'm not sure where to start, any suggestions greatly appreciated...many thanks.

This is the javascript

```
$(function(){
$("#quantity").parent().children().css("vertical-align","middle")
});

function btnminus(a){
document.getElementById("quantity").value>a?
document.getElementById("quantity").value--:
document.getElementById("quantity").value=a
}

function btnplus(a){
document.getElementById("quantity").value<a?
document.getElementById("quantity").value++:
document.getElementById("quantity").value=a
}
```

This is the html

```
<div class="box">    
    <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
    <input id="quantity" value="1" />
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnminus(1)">-</button>
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnplus(10);$(this).prev().val(~~$(this).prev().val()+1);$(this).parents('form');">+</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="box">    
    <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
    <input id="quantity" value="1" />
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnminus(1)">-</button>
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnplus(10);$(this).prev().val(~~$(this).prev().val()+1);$(this).parents('form');">+</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="box">    
    <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
    <input id="quantity" value="1" />
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnminus(1)">-</button>
    <button id="quantity" onclick="btnplus(10);$(this).prev().val(~~$(this).prev().val()+1);$(this).parents('form');">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use many ID's, this is mistake, [ID must be only one for ONE page](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).

```
$(function() {
  $('.box').on('click', '.minus', function () {
    var $quantity = $(this).siblings('.quantity'),
        value     = +$quantity.val();

    if (value > 1) {
      $quantity.val(value - 1);
    }
  });

  $('.box').on('click', '.plus', function () {
    var $quantity = $(this).siblings('.quantity'),
        value     = +$quantity.val();

    if (value < 10) {
      $quantity.val(value + 1);
    }
  });
});


<div class="box">    
  <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
  <input value="1" class="quantity" />
  <button class="minus">-</button>
  <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

DEMO:

- http://jsfiddle.net/aeuLx9nt/6/
- [http://jsbin.com/sibejo/1/](http://jsbin.com/sibejo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @ Alexander That's awesome working perfectly now. Thanks very much, I spent many, many hours trying to resolve this myself & got nowhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("quantity") will find the first element with that ID.

You are using that ID for every input. So it will only ever affect the first one. Only use IDs once.

Comment: @ hello_world I have duplicated the html blocks only to illustrate the problem I am getting in the cart with multiple products added. This is the exact same effect I am getting on the demo site?